When cookies are set in a Server Action (SA), why does Server Component parents to Client Component that called SA not see the new cookie value?
When setting cookies with a Server Action ("SA") (Next.js docs), how come the Server Component parent of the Client Component ("CC") that called the SA cannot see the updated cookies right away?
After calling the SA, the CC and the parent SC re-renders, but as seen below, no cookies are present after the SA ran.

Clicking around the application does not help. The cookies do not show in the SC log until another request is sent to the route (i.e. a browser reload).
Note: Several unofficial articles claim that SCs never re-render, but looking at the server-side logs we see that the SC does indeed re-render when the CC re-renders. Which is why I expected the new cookies to be picked up.
Minimal reproducible example (code also below): https://github.com/magnusriga/server-action
SC:
import { ClientComponent2 } from "./client-component2";
import { ClientComponent } from "./client-component";
import { headers } from "next/headers";

function wait(ms: number) {
  return new Promise<number>((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    const _headers = new Map(headers());
    resolve(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    console.log('headers in promise after resolve', _headers);
  }, ms))
}

export default async function Home() {
  // const promise = wait(3000);
  const value = await wait(3000);
  console.log('headers in component body', new Map(headers())); // This runs again when ClientComponent2 re-renders.

  return (
    <div className="font-sans grid grid-rows-[20px_1fr_20px] items-center justify-items-center min-h-screen p-8 pb-20 gap-16 sm:p-20">
      <main className="flex flex-col gap-8 row-start-2 items-center sm:items-start">
        {/* <ClientComponent promise={promise}/> */}
        <ClientComponent2 value={value}/>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

CC:
'use client'

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { setCookiesAction } from "@/action";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export function ClientComponent({promise}: {promise: Promise<number>}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [data, setData] = useState<number | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('in useEffect, promise is', promise)
    promise.then((data) => {
      console.log('promise resolved inside useEffect, setting data state next, data is:', data)
      setData(data)
    })
  }, [promise]);

  async function actionHandler() {
    console.log('before running SA')
    const saReturn = await setCookiesAction(data ?? 0)
    console.log('after SA, return value was', saReturn)
    setData(saReturn)
    // router.refresh()
  }

  return (
    <div className="bg-black/[.05] dark:bg-white/[.06] p-4 rounded text-sm">
      {data === null ? "Loading..." : `Random number: ${data}`}
      <button onClick={actionHandler} className="block mt-4 p-2 bg-black/[.1] dark:bg-white/[.1] rounded text-white dark:text-black"> Click To Set Cookies</button>
    </div>
  );
}

SA:
'use server'

import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache"
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export async function setCookiesAction(num: number) {
  cookies().set('name', 'value')
  // revalidatePath('/')
  return num
}

